# Leverage Browser Caching in site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, browser-cache, mod-expires

I have developed my site using magento and anguar js. From google page Insights, I got that I have to leverage browser caching. So for that, I have defined my .htaccess file lke this:

```
 RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ story.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !facebookexternalhit/[0-9]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     # YEAR
     <FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|flv|pdf)$">
          Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400"
     </FilesMatch>
     # WEEK
     <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf|woff)$">
         Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
     </FilesMatch>
     # 45 MIN
     <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|txt)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400"
     </FilesMatch>

     Header set Connection keep-alive

</IfModule>
```

But this is not working as the google insight is still showing the same message.

Comment: Try using `mod_expires` instead: https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_expires

Comment: should I use it in apache cnf file or htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mod_expires` to check which assets should be reloaded after a certain time. In your `.htaccess` file you can configure it like so:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/json "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

As you can see there is an `ExpiresDefault` of 2years from access time on. For all images and javascripts you can spot the time. If you need other values you can find extensive docs here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html